# is there any way to fetch data on same page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am stuck in this code,please help me.

```
<div class="box box-info">
     <div class="box-header with-border">
          <a href='admin_dashboard.php?option=borrow' class='btn btn-danger'>borrow detail</a>||<a href='dashboard.php?option=lender' class='btn btn-danger'>lender detail</a>
      <br/>
      <br/>
```

```
<?php
      $option = isset($_REQUEST['option'])==TRUE?$_REQUEST['option']:"";
      // echo $option;
      if($option=='borrow')
      {
         include('borrow_detail.php');
      }else{
           include('lend_detail.php');
     }
  ?>
```

how to change this code in codeigniter.

Comment: can't clear your question plz explain more..@Harsh Jain

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Answer (score -1):

From what i understand i guess you need to convert your posted `php` code to `codeigniter`.Here is how you can do it:

```
$option = $this->input->get('option')?$this->input->get('option'):"";
  if($option=='borrow')
  {
     $this->load->view('borrow_detail.php');         
  }else{
     $this->load->view('lend_detail.php');
 }
```

Comment: ok. how can i  call  href or page name with admin_dashboard.php?option=borrow .this is not redirect to any page and showing 404 error.

Comment: Post your complete code along with your complete case scenario to get any help

Comment: Dear down voter,explain the reason for down vote and help us improve our experience.

Comment: @Bira If you think its helpful,you can up vote it .. :)

Comment: I agree with @Bira, why they have authority to downvote if they did not even test or execute the answer, I upvoted this one :D